# What is a Scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Probably sounds like a stupid question, but it's not something I've ever needed to use (unless I'm calling it something else in my head).

I know what a frame is, and I use them all the time, but what is a scene?

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay()

  `public function gotoAndPlay(frame:Object, scene:String = null):void`

Comment: It's analogous to a scene in a movie, for the most part. You probably don't often use scenes when you're not working on an animation/movie in Flash, though.

Comment: In ten years of professional Flash development, I have never made use of the concept of scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this document from the help of Flash :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7eb3a.html